# Batch script with %date% variable

Tags: scripting, batch

I do robocopy using .bat script, this script is starting 22PM before midnight and it took over 5 hours to complete. The problem is that destination folder is created with date \nas01\%date% so when it starts let's say is 10.07.2019 but when robocopy job cross midnight then new destination is created - 11.07.2019 And I have two folders for my backup. How could I resolve this? (I cannot change start time the backup). thanks

Comment: Create a local variable with DATE, e.g.: `SET DMY=%DATE%` and then use `%DMY%` instead of `%DATE%` for your destination. Would that work?

Comment: thanks this is working ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a local variable with DATE, e.g.: `SET DMY=%DATE%` and then use `%DMY%` instead of `%DATE%` for your destination.